# Generating 3 random numbers and saving them in database

Tags: php, custom-field

I need to generate 3 ramdom numbers everyday at 16:00 gmt o'clock and save(add) them on 3 diferent tables with date.

DB name: Wp_Funlottery

Tables: Number01 , Number02, Number03

Fields: id (secuense / Number (XX) / Date (dd/mm/yyyy)

Comment: And what is preventing you from doing that? Please explain your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

date_default_timezone_set('GMT');

$today = date('H:i');

for($i=1; $i<=365; $i++)
{
     $repeat = strtotime("+1 day",strtotime($today));
     $today = date('g:i a',$repeat);

}

$date1 = date("1:09 a");

//IMPORTANT:  This must be at the top of your page1.html before anything is sent to browser!
if($today==$date1){

$random1 = rand(00,99);

$random2 = rand(00,99);

$random3 = rand(00,99);

$randate1 = date('Y-m-d');

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "funlotto", "5K39S3p2!g", "funlotto");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Attempt insert query execution
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO lotto_1 (number, date) VALUES (".$random1.", now())";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql1)){
    echo "Records inserted successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO lotto_2 (number, date) VALUES (".$random2.", now())";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql2)){
    echo "Records inserted successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
$sql3 = "INSERT INTO lotto_3 (number, date) VALUES (".$random3.", now())";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql3)){
    echo "Records inserted successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);

```
exit;
```

}